# bootstrap-timepicker-rails doesn't work in my Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails.
I've been tring bootstrap-timepicker-rails gem in my Rails4 application but it's doesn't work.
https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails'

group :doc do
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

$('.t_picker').timepicker()
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap-timepicker
*= require_tree .
```

/event/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :location %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :location %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.fields_for :schedules do |sch| %>
 <%= sch.time_field :start %>
 <%= sch.time_field :end %>
 <%= sch.text_field :description %> 
 <% end %>
 <div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "it doesn't work."  The widget that you're supposed to click doesn't appear?  It appears, but doesn't look right? It *does* appear, but when you click on it the time picker popup doesn't appear?

Comment: Also, since this is a JavaScript-based widget, try opening your browser console and reloading the page, to see if there are any errors.  If there are, use that to help diagnose the problem, or add them to your problem description above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need this, but I made it work for me (Rails 4 app) by using the 'modal' template & setting specifically the id of my field, like this:

```
=f.input :time, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'bootstrap-timepicker', :id => 'time'}
```

& in the script, like this:

```
$('#time').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 15,
etc etc..
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<%= sch.time_field :start %>
<%= sch.time_field :end %>
```

to this:

```
<%= sch.time_field :start, class: 't_picker' %>
<%= sch.time_field :end, class: 't_picker' %>
```

Maybe it will help.

Comment: I've tried this before. But is doesn't work either and I've puted  <input id ="asdf" type='text' class= "t_picker" > in my _form.html.erb files but nothing effect will apper.